# How do I exclude cells in my Formatting Cells Based On Content macro?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

[Before and after photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y6bk.jpg)

[image]

I am using a handy VBA script that changes hard-coded values to a bright blue font.

It works well, except for recoloring my dates which are often white font with dark background (I don't want these to change). The dates always use a date number format. Is there a way to exclude numbers that are formatted as dates from the following?

```
Sub FormatCellsBasedOnContent()
 'color format macro
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection
   
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Blue
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)   ' Black

    
End Sub
```

If this is not possible, is there another way to exclude these cells? For example, maybe exclude anything with a background color or exclude EOMONTH/DATE/EDATE formulas?  I tried this, and it does not work.

```
Sub FormatCellsBasedOnContent()
 'color format macro
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection
   
       For Each cell In Selection
       If Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" Then ''
       ElseIf Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]mmm-yy;@" Then ''
       
       Else
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Blue
       Else
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)   ' Black
       End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Selection.NumberFormat` should be `If cell.NumberFormat` - you're only working on one cell at a time...     `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` will be True for cells with no fill color.

Comment: Same outcome. The Date headers are changing to black and blue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub FormatCellsBasedOnContent()
 
    Dim cell As Range, v
    
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If Not cell.NumberFormat Like "*yy*" Then 'looks like a date?
            If cell.HasFormula Then               'has a formula?
                cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
            Else
                v = cell.Value
                If Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then 'number?
                    cell.Font.Color = vbBlue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, It tried this and it takes so long to run that it is faster to run the other macro and then manually adjust the headers. Another thing is that it still changes this formula to black even though it is text... "=REPLACE(@CELL("filename",A1),1,FIND("]",@CELL("filename",A1)),"")" The other version does this as well.

Comment: It might be useful to show a screenshot of the type of data you're working with.  Or if you can share a sample file (redacted as necessary) that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Tim! Sure thing - I have updated the post to include a link to the photo.  - Red box= what I am trying to prevent. - The Green box = what I want to keep.  You can see that row 4 includes the name of the worksheet (formula is ="2024 BUDGET - "&REPLACE(@CELL("filename",B1),1,FIND("]",@CELL("filename",B1)),"")) and dates (formula =EOMONTH(E4,1) but this varies...two other common formulas we use for dates are edate or hardcoded date + 7).

Comment: So the date "Oct-22" is hard-coded but the other dates are formulas? I couldn't get that value to turn blue running the code I posted, because it's filtered out due to the number format

Comment: Yes, Oct 22 is hardcoded, but I don't want it blue, so that is ideal! Thank you. The issues that I am having with the code you posted ...    1. It seems to run cell by cell, which is much slower than the original code. If I have data in A1:X85000 it takes about 30 seconds. 2. It only works on selected cells, so I have to manually scroll over and down to ensure everything is captured. If I select all, it runs for 12+ minutes.     Is there a way to have the code read cells that are not blank instead of manually selecting the range? I am thinking that might speed it up.

Comment: As a side note, =REPLACE(@CELL("filename",A1),1,FIND("]",@CELL("filename",A1)),"") the code still changes this text to black, but I was able to find a good workaround for this (switched the number format from general to Date)

Comment: "It only works on selected cells" - there's nothing in your question which suggests that's *not* what you wanted?  There are plenty of example posts here on SO asking about how to find the last-occupied cell on a worksheet (or you can just use UsedRange instead...)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to include your exceptions and still make it fast.  Likely the workaround is to do as you mentioned: revert any unwanted changes (assuming you know the locations of those cells)